# Automatically build a manually installed kernel module upon installing a kernel update on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, kernel-modules

I am experimenting with [flashcache](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache) on my Ubuntu and it looks interesting enough to do a long term test with it. I downloaded the sources, compiled them and installed the resulting kernel module. So far so good.

But once I update my Operating System and a new kernel is installed, the module needs to be recompiled for the new kernel and installed in a different path.

I am sure this can be done automatically, but I don't know how. Whenever I update the kernel on my system, serveral modules are automatically compiled (amongst others the virualbox modules).

How can I automatically recompile a manually installed kernel module upon upgrading my kernel package? I basically need some hook that does the `make` and `make install` stages for flashcache during an `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: The ones that are automatically built are probably using dkms. You can add your own modules to it (or possibly Debian's flashcache-dkms package will work on Ubuntu, or will be imported into universe soon enough—or at least will show you how to add it)

Comment: Yes I just found some dkms docs too, which I'm studying right now. Initially I thought it was about installing a module in initramfs, but it seems to be more than just that.

Comment: If you figure out the steps to add it to DKMS (and there is a README-DKMS in the flashcache repo that may help), please feel encouraged to answer your own question here.

Comment: For this particular case I needed to change the supplied `Makefile.dkms` file because I downloaded the zip and not the full GIT repository as follows: `COMMIT_REV := 2.0.0`. Just guessing about the 2.0.0, but it can't be all too wrong because the zip file has a v2 extension. Then run the makefile: `make -f Makefile.dkms`. The Makefile.dkms isn't too hard to read, but requires quite a few man pages to be studied.

Comment: As a side effect I start to understand Makefiles a bit better too ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "usual" way is to use [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) (initially developed by Dell to support specific drivers for their servers under Linux). Even nVidia has now an integration of their graphic-card-driver with DKMS - that driver needs to be recompiled with every kernel-update, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a

> $ make help

in the kernel source directory, you will see among others

> ...
>   Kernel packaging:
>     deb-pkg             - Build the kernel as a deb package
>     ...

`make deb-pkg` builds several kernel related packages:

- linux-firmware-image_*.deb
- linux-headers-*.deb
- linux-image-*.deb
- linux-libc-dev_*.deb

Comment: Not exactly an answer that addresses the question, though 'deb-pkg' is a very cool thing. For anyone who finds this, however, I highly recommend `make bindeb-pkg` instead, unless you really really need the source packages (or something to that extent) that it will spend a good chunk of time building otherwise, and that you'll spend a good chunk of time and storage space installing.